# GiT pipeline to invoke lambda function created using terraform,

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, command-line-interface

```
stages:
  - validate
  - plan
  - apply
  - invoke
  
image:
  name: hashicorp/terraform:light
  entrypoint:
    - '/usr/bin/env'
    - 'PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'
before_script:
  - set TF_VAR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
  - set TF_VAR_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY} 
  - rm -rf .terraform
  - terraform --version
  - terraform init


validate:
  stage: validate
  script:
    - terraform validate
plan:
  stage: plan
  script:
    - terraform plan -out "planfile"
  dependencies:
    - validate
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - planfile
apply:
  stage: apply
  script:
    - terraform apply -input=false "planfile"
  dependencies:
    - plan
  
invoke:
  stage: invoke
 
  script:      
      - set func_name = ${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}-"hello-world" 
      - aws lambda invoke --function-name '$func-name' response.json
  dependencies:
    - apply
```

In the above script, in invoke stage i want to pass the lambda function main as argument, lambda function name prefixed with the gitlab branch name.

I am getting function arg syntax error.

Could someone help in finding a solution to pass the function name arg  prefixed with gitlab branch name to AWS lambda invoke CLI command.

Answer (score 0):

Gitlab branch name environment variable is `CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` [https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html#:~:text=branches%20or%20tags.-,CI_COMMIT_BRANCH,-12.6](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html#:%7E:text=branches%20or%20tags.-,CI_COMMIT_BRANCH,-12.6)

You don't need to create any extra variables.

```
invoke:
  stage: invoke
 
  script:      
      - aws lambda invoke --function-name "${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}-hello-world" response.json
  dependencies:
    - apply
```

If you want to use it with variables.

```
invoke:
  stage: invoke
 
  script:      
      - func_name="${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}-hello-world" 
      - aws lambda invoke --function-name "$func_name" response.json
  dependencies:
    - apply
```